# How do I run ellipse detection on scikit-image for python on local images?

Tags: python, object-detection, scikit-image, ellipse, hough-transform

The scikit-image processing example code for circular and elliptical hough transformations and ellipse detection identifies ellipses in an image (link: [scikit example code](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html)). However, the example only allows me to run the code on images from the scikit data directory. I cannot run the code on a local image.

I have tried merging the path to my local file with the path to the scikit data directory using `os.path.join()`. This does not seem to be working.

Any suggestions for how to run this example ellipse detection code on a locally stored image?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to read image and convert to grey:

---

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2grey
image = imread("<full path to image>")
image = rgb2grey(image)
edges = canny(image, sigma=3, low_threshold=10, high_threshold=50)
```

---